# Using XML to populate an HTML page based on user defined options

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

I have a list of products that I want to return to the user depending on their selection from 3 options. The kicker is that this has to be a static page with nothing more fancy than javascript, HTML and XML. The form will be along the lines of:

```
<label for="field_1">How much are you spending?</label><select name="field_1" id="cf_field_1" class="cformselect" >
            <option value="sub10">Less than £10</option>
            <option value="10-20">£10 - £20</option>
            <option value="20-30">£20 - £30</option>
            <option value="30-40">£30 - £40</option>
        </select>

<label for="field_2">Colour?</label><select name="field_2" id="cf_field_2" class="cformselect" >
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        </select>

<label for="field_3">What is most important?</label><select name="field_3" id="cf_field_3" class="cformselect" >
            <option value="taste">Taste</option>
            <option value="look">How it looks</option>
            <option value="transport">How easy it is to carry</option>
        </select>
```

There are 7 possible product and often there is more than one to suit the selected criteria - but also times when nothing is suitable. With the questions I have that makes 48 possible results. Its possible that more products will be added in time.

The return will be a description of the product in formatted text (happy to hold it in the HTML rather than XML).

I'm thinking that the XML will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<productset>
  <product>
    <name>Prod 1</name>
    <value>sub10</value>
    <value>10-20</value>
    <colour>red</colour>
    <colour>blue</colour>
    <colour>yellow</colour>
    <feature>taste</feature>
    <body>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>
        <a href="/prod_1.html"></a>
      </p>
    </body>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Prod 2</name>
    <value>20-30</value>
    <colour>red</colour>
    <colour>yellow</colour>
    <feature>taste</feature>
    <body>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>
        <a href="/prod_2.html"></a>
      </p>
    </body>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Prod 3</name>
    <value>sub10</value>
    <value>30-40</value>
    <colour>red</colour>
    <colour>yellow</colour>
    <feature>carry</feature>
    <body>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>
        <a href="/prod_3.html"></a>
      </p>
    </body>
  </product>
</productset>
```

I'm new to this level and so any and all help would be really appreciated in how to get the right products returned.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have your retrieved XML string in a variable called `xml`:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml_obj = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
// now xml_obj is a DOM document
var products = xml_obj.getElementsByTagName("products");
// then process it as you need
for(var i=0; i < products.length; i++){
    console.log("Found product: " + products[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent);       
}
```

This will take some work, so you may consider using jQuery or some similar library, which should reduce a lot the code to access the values. See [this](http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do what you need just using xpath (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp)
 although it is a bit of an arse to make browser compatible!